# Are questions that ask for an explanation of (erratic) behavior on-topic if a work-around has already been found?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

My specific case:

I'm developing an Android app and was using a flag in an `Intent` to bring an `Activity` to front instead of re-creating it. It worked, mostly as expected. The `EditText` in a `Fragment` (that was inside the `Activity`) broke, for lack of a better term. Despite its name, the `EditText` could *not* be edited, and attempting to do so would crash the application.

After extensive trial and error, and pro Google skills, I found a property that could be declared in `Manifest.xml`:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

I declared that where I needed to and everything works perfectly fine (problem solved!).

However, I'm still wondering why the `EditText` was 'broken' (uneditable, attempting to type/delete/etc crashed the app). I've *solved* my problem, but the problem shouldn't have occurred in the first place. Would a well-formed question regarding the *why* of the behavior (and looking for a solution for the previous method I was using) be on-topic even if I've already found another solution that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say yes.  Work arounds are a nice thing, but they have side effects.  Besides, finding the real answer would help you see other potential problems coming at you.  Just be sure to word your question well (that you're curious why this is the case, rather than looking for how to fix it necessarily).  Mentioning the workaround may help too, as a clue to readers for what's actually happening.